# Cannot Reproduce the Splitting of Train and Test using sklearn

Tags: python, split

I am currently using Jupyter Notebook version 5.6.0 through the Anaconda Navigator. I am trying to split my dataset to Training and Testing but whenever I shutdown and reopen my notebook and rerun the code, it creates a different training and testing set. The random_state works though if I just rerun the code without shutting down the notebook. Is this normal? Is there a way to fix this such that eve though I close and reopen the notebook, it would still split the dataset the same way>

I have set the random state of the train_test_split method but it still produces a different data split.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Split dataset into Training and Testing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

y = train['Target']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 0)
x_train.head()
```

The result from the first run is this:

```
      |   ID        |    Country           |   Target

7093  |   9.56      |      Tokyo           |    Yes

5053  |   9.58      |      Bangkok         |    Yes

1627  |   9.53      |      New York        |    No

2514  |   9.55      |      Los Angeles     |    No
```

Rerun values shows:

```
      |   ID        |    Country           |   Target

3805  |   9.51      |     Chicago          |    No

6730  |   9.59      |     Seattle          |    No

7623  |   9.57      |     Busan            |    Yes

7045  |   9.60      |     Seoul            |    Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Where and how do you get your testing data from? If your data comes from a dynamic source (a random generated data, data from a server, or if you are reducing the data, by picking random values from it) it will couse suck an issue.
I would usually solve the problem, by creating a copy of my data, so that I can refer to it liter,by using `pickle.io`. This code assumes that I've already have my data as a dataframe:

```
df.to_pickle(file_name)
```

Next I would simply use the data I hava stored, using:

```
df = pd.read_pickle(file_name)
```

Then
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the random state in [numpy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it still produces a different result.

Comment: I've tried it on a fake dataset I generated, and it works fine. My setup: ```numpy==1.16.3
pandas==0.24.2
scikit-learn==0.21.1
```. Do you get different results if you run it in straight python? Outside Anaconda Navigator/Jupyter?

Comment: Still got different result when I ran it outside python. My setup is np ==1.15.4, pd ==0.23.4 and sklearn ==0.19.2